# rasa handle_message("my_message") gives me none result

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

`agent.handle_message("hi")` gives me a None result in my code. I loaded interpreter correctly.

When i run interpreter.parse("my_message"), it gives me correct result.

Comment: Hi @Dunshan,

How did you initialise your agent?  Did you train or load a model with it?  Sounds like it may be missing a domain or policy ensemble.

Comment: @TomMetcalfe i trained my model using `rasa train`. What may be the problem?

Comment: In that case you don't need to pass an interpreter.  If you used `rasa train` without the `nlu` or `core` mode then the full stacked model will be saved as a `.tar.gz` in the `models` directory.  Load that with `agent = Agent.load('path/to/model.tar.gz')` and then you can handle text with `asyncio.run(agent.handle_text("hello"))` (or `await agent.handle_text("hello")` if it's inside a function).

Here's the [docs page on agents](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/agent/#rasa.core.agent.Agent.handle_text)